# Is it possible to test an Abstract activity with Robolectric

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, android-testing

I use abstract activity classes in my code to well, abstract away some features from the activity classes.

I'm trying to test the abstract activity classes using `Robolectric` and the `gradle-android-test-plugin` using subclasses that extend the abstract class. I can't seem to get it to work though.

Does anyone have any experience in this area and is it even possible ? Basic structure is :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class AbstractActivityTest {
    private ActivityTest activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(ActivityTest.class).create().get();
    }


    private class ActivityTest extends AbstractActivity {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Initially, I got the error message the sub class wasn't static so I made it static. Now I get the following two fails:

```
initializationError FAILED
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor

initializationError FAILED
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
```

Any obviously true tests I put in `@Test` methods succeed.

Comment: What exactly is not working?. Is there any error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error saying that you added non-default constructor to your test class or changed access level for default one. But as it says `junit` Test class should have at least one public constructor.

The second one says that at least one method in test class should have `@Test` annotation (`junit 4`) or starts with test substring (`junit 3`).

Answer (score 3):

Yo can doing exactly what you are trying to do: subclass the abstract activity and instance the concrete class.

However, you need to declare the class extending the abstract Activity in it's own public file. If it's a nested class Robolectric will fail to instance it.

I don't know why, though.

Comment: If I define the class in the same file as the test class but not as a nested class, it also works for me. I did not have to put it in its own file.

Answer (score 0):

I test an abstract activity this way:

**1. Creating the abstract avtivity:**

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int getNumber() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**2. Creating the test class:**

You just need to declare a **static** nested subclass of your abstract class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AbstractActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void checkNumberReturn() throws Exception {
        TestAbstractActivity testAbstractActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(TestAbstractActivity.class);
        assertThat(testAbstractActivity.getNumber(), is(2));
    }

    public static class TestAbstractActivity extends AbstractActivity {
    }
}
```