# How to test android abstract activity?

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

I have a BaseActivity which is an abstract activity and isn't registered in AndroidManifest. BaseActivity will call getPresenter in activity's lifecycle.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public abstract Presenter getPresenter;
    public abstract int getLayout();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayout());
        getPresenter().attachView(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getPresenter().detachView();
    }
}
```

I use ActivityTestRule to launch the BaseActivity, but the following error is shown.
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity`

How to test the `getPresenter().attachView(this)` and `getPresenter().detachView()` are called in correct activity's lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have quite big experience with Android Testing, especially unit testing, but I've already found this post, which may be useful for you:
[Is it possible to test an Abstract activity with Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558927/is-it-possible-to-test-an-abstract-activity-with-robolectric)

Also on Github page of Robolectric I'd found this: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1441

So all I can say according to your question, that yes you can  test your abstract class, at least with Robolectric.

Read also: https://gualtierotesta.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/tutorial-java-abstract-classes-testing/

EDIT: Nowadays, Robolectric doesn't support directly API 23, but you can "downgrade" it in configuration of test class, like below:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MainActivityTest {

    MainActivity_ activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

}
```

Comment: I have read the post, but Robolectric doesn't support android SDK level 23. Still thanks for this information!

Comment: Be patient, they working on it: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1865#issuecomment-167267371

Comment: Oh! I forgot to update my Robolectric version.  I will try again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The error is shown because the BaseActivity isn't registered in Android Manifest. It seems that there are some solutions to add an activity in test package.

However, I finally choose another solution, delegate the activity's lifecycle to others. 
This idea is mentioned in Mosby playbook.

http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby-playbook/

New BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseMvpView, DelegateCallback{

private ActivityMvpDelegate activityDelegate;

    protected ActivityMvpDelegate getActivityDelegate() {
        if (activityDelegate == null) {
            activityDelegate = createActivityDelegate();
        }
        return activityDelegate;
    }

    protected ActivityMvpDelegate createActivityDelegate() {
        return new ActivityMvpDelegateImpl(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivityDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivityDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Finally, I can test the delegate class without activity's lifecycle.